# iOS 11 : Cellular Signal strength

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, iphone-privateapi, cellular-network

I was fetching Cellular Signal Strength(iOS < 11) as mentioned below, but in iOS 11 , signalStrength is always 0

```
  let statusBarView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
            if let foregroundView = statusBarView?.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as? UIView {
                let subiews = foregroundView.subviews
                var dataNetworkItemView:UIView?
                for subview in subiews {
                    if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) == true {
                        dataNetworkItemView = subview
                        break
                    }
                }
                var signalStrength = 0
                var signalStrengthBars = 0
                if let view = dataNetworkItemView {
                    signalStrength = view.value(forKey: "signalStrengthRaw") as! Int
                    signalStrengthBars = view.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int
                }
```

Comment: This was never supposed to work, it uses private APIs. You should not do this. If you want to monitor the network, use `Reachability`

Comment: I am not concern about apple review, so use of private API does not concern me. I have already added tag of Private API, please see that before commenting.

Comment: Whosoever downvoted this, give me a valid reason